# Can't start asp.net debug in http

Tags: visual-studio, ssl

I have an issue which is driving me mad. 
I have a project which I set up and enabled SSL (By changing the SSL enabled flag to true in the application properties)

[image]

Then I changed the project url in the web properties to the SSL Url (Shown in the image above)

[image]

And finally, I added a rewrite rule to my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This was all fine. I was able to debug my application while on the new HTTPS url. The problem is now I have to test it back on HTTP, so I reversed my steps. 
First I commented out the rewrite rule, then I changed the Project Url back to the normal http url and clicked "Create Virtual Directory".
And finally I changed the "SSL Enabled" to false.

This is where the problem lies. When I press F5, my browser uses the normal URL (The correct http one) but it redirects to a https url. I can't change it because when I do it just redirects.
It is driving me mad because there is no rule (that I can find) that is redirecting it. I even uncommented my rewrite rule and changed it to this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

To for it to use the http url, but it will not.
Can someone please help me?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was pretty straight forward. I commented out the rewrite rule and then in the project properties, just set the **override application root url** to the http url while keeping the **project url** as the https version.